# I have an error when running my foldTree function

Tags: haskell, fold

I want to write a treeFold function that takes: A function f of type 'a -> b -> a, A value x of type a, A Tree b named t, and returns a value of type a. The return value is computed by performing an in-order traversal of the Tree, passing along the partial results via x.
HERE IS MY CODE:

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Control.DeepSeq
import qualified Data.List as List
import Test.HUnit

data Tree a  =  Empty
             |  Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
             deriving (Show, Eq)



insertTree :: ( Ord a, Show a ) => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
insertTree Empty x  =  Node x Empty Empty
insertTree ( Node v tLeft tRight ) x
    | x == v = Node v tLeft tRight
    | x < v = Node v (insertTree tLeft x) tRight
    | x > v = Node v tLeft (insertTree tRight x)


createTree :: ( Ord a, Show a ) => [ a ] -> Tree a
createTree = foldl insertTree Empty
```

intTree = createTree [ 9, 7, 2, 8, 6, 0, 5, 3, 1 ]

```
listTree = createTree ( List.permutations [ 0 .. 3 ] )

strTree = createTree [ "hello"
                     , "world"
                     , "lorem"
                     , "ipsum"
                     , "dolor"
                     , "sit"
                     , "amet"
                     ]
treeFold :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f z Empty = z
treeFold f z (Node v l r) = f v (subfold l) (subfold r)
    where subfold = foldTree f z
```

But when I run the code, I got a "Couldn't match type error". I was wondering how can I fix this problem? for exmaple: Main> treeFold (+) 10 intTree, instead of getting Main> 51, i got could't match type error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the type of the first argument that `treeFold` expects: `a -> b -> b -> b`.  Now look at the type of `(+)`: `(Num a) => a -> a -> a`.  They do not match.  You need to supply a function of three arguments, but `(+)` only accepts two arguments.

Comment: here is the fixed treeFold code: treeFold :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> Tree b -> a
treeFold f z Empty = z
treeFold f z (Node l x r) =
 treeFold f (f x (treeFold f z r)) l...  But is till get the sam e error.

Comment: Your original `treeFold` code was correct.  The error was that you supplied it with `(+)` as an argument.  You need to supply something other than `(+)` to `treeFold`.

Answer (score 1):

In your function

```
treeFold :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f z Empty = z
treeFold f z (Node v l r) = f v (subfold l) (subfold r)
    where subfold = foldTree f z
```

you use `f` on three values: `v`, `(subfold l)` and `(subfold r)`. This is why your type signature requires `f` to take three arguments.

It seems to me that you'd be better off applying a two-argument `f` twice, once to combine `v` and `(subfold l)`, the other to combine that with `(subfold r)`:

```
treeFold f z Empty = z
treeFold f z (Node v l r) = f (f v (subfold l)) (subfold r)
    where subfold = treeFold f z
```

That does mean that if we assume `f :: a -> b -> c`, then `subfold l :: b` because of `f v (subfold l)`, but also `subfold l :: c` because it's returned from `treeFold`. Thus `c` and `b` are the same type (`c ~ b`), and `f v (subfold l) :: b`. That's used as the first argument of the first `f`, so `a ~ b` too. Thus for this new use-f-twice version,

```
treeFold :: (b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree b -> b
```